# Using a bypass capacitor with a no-neutral smart light switch on two lamps in series?

Tags: switches, bypass, smart

I am considering purchasing a smart light switch which does not require a neutral wire and instead works with a bypass capacitor parallel to the load lamp. This switch would control two lamps in series, however, and it will not be easy to install the capacitor such that it is connected to the one side of the first lamp and the second side of the second lamp. Can I use two capacitors (of double value each?) each connected parallel to each of the two laps?

Instead of this:

[image: smart switch with bypass capacitor]

This:

[image: smart switch with two bypass capacitors]

Comment: It concerns me that you have two lamps wired in series. What would happen if one was (say) 5 watt rated and another placed in series was 60 watt rated. Do you know what will happen?

Comment: They’re two identical lamps in a kitchen hood which came with the apartment and one switch controls them both, so I suppose they’re probably parallel then based on what you’re saying, which means one bypass capacitor would be enough

Comment: If you remove one lamp, does the other still shine?